# How to sort queryset by another table's record count in Django

Tags: python, django

I have a Product table and order table
the Product table record product info,and the Order table record customer's purchases records

Now I want to get the products queryset and sort by the store with the most purchases in a customer's order history

### Product Model

| id | product_name | store_id | store_name | price | ..... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | iPhone 14 | 1 | Amazon | 100 | ..... |
| 2 | iPhone 14 | 2 | Shopee | 1 | ..... |
| 3 | iPhone 12 | 3 | Taobao | 100 | ..... |
| 4 | iPhone 13 | 1 | Amazon | 80 | ..... |
| 5 | iPhone 14 | 3 | Taobao | 100 | ..... |

### Order Model

| id | product_id | customer_id | customer_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | Mike |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | Mike |
| 3 | 4 | 1 | Mike |
| 4 | 1 | 2 | Jhon |
| 5 | 3 | 3 | Simon |

in my case,I want to get the product's queryset and sort by the store with the most purchases in a customer's order history

For example:

when customer_id is 1（Mike）,the product queryset should be like below because Mike have spent the most times on Amazon, so the ordering of products should put Amazon's products first

| id | product_name | store_id | store_name | price | ..... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | iPhone 14 | 1 | Amazon | 100 | ..... |
| 4 | iPhone 13 | 1 | Amazon | 80 | ..... |
| 2 | iPhone 14 | 2 | Shopee | 1 | ..... |
| 3 | iPhone 12 | 3 | Taobao | 100 | ..... |
| 5 | iPhone 14 | 3 | Taobao | 100 | ..... |

In the same case,when customer_id is 3(Simon),the product queryset should be like below,because Mike have spent the most times on Taobao

| id | product_name | store_id | store_name | price | ..... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | iPhone 12 | 3 | Taobao | 100 | ..... |
| 5 | iPhone 14 | 3 | Taobao | 100 | ..... |
| 1 | iPhone 14 | 1 | Amazon | 100 | ..... |
| 2 | iPhone 14 | 2 | Shopee | 1 | ..... |
| 4 | iPhone 13 | 1 | Amazon | 80 | ..... |

I user count and filter in Django ,code below, but it executes the result is wrong
customer_id = 1 # Mike

```
product_set = Product.objects.annotate(count=Count('order__store_id', filter=Q(order__customer_id=customer_id, order__store__id=F('store_id')))).order_by('-count')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you what you want is, if apple is a product and
store 1 sold it 15 times
store 2 sold it 25 times

then product apple with store id 1 comes on top

so for this:

```
from django.db.models import Count
Product.objects.annotate(store_count=Count('store_id')).order_by('-store_count')
```

or

```
queryset.objects.annotate(store_count=Count('store_id')).order_by('-store_count')
```

this will create a temporary field `store_count` and `Count('store_id')` will count product occurrences with store_id and then order it.

Comment: not right,, I want is the result will be sort by the customer's buy times in the store, just like a recommendation algorithm. will recommend the product is sold by the store which the customer has consumed most times

Comment: You mean, if I bought 8 times and you bought 10 times a same product  then most ordered product comes first??

Comment: No, it has nothing to do with different people,I use this api interface to return some products for one user. So I want to rank products from the store he has purchased the most